# Why data post to only user under APP is created to facebook using ImpactWorks.FBGraph in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I created an app using my Facebook profile. I have implemented functionality to my asp.net MVC web project to post in Facebook. but it can post data to only my profile. When other authorized users post data on their wall it returns the error "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden". I have used the Graph API to post in Facebook.

Can anyone give me a solution for this? Is there any setting in the created app?

My redirect action is

```
public ActionResult Success()
        {
 PostToFacebookWall auth = new PostToFacebookWall();
            string Code = Request.QueryString["code"];

            if (Code != null)
            {
                ImpactWorks.FBGraph.Connector.Facebook facebook = auth.FacebookAuth();
                facebook.GetAccessToken(Code.ToString());
                FBUser currentUser = facebook.GetLoggedInUserInfo();
                IFeedPost FBpost = new FeedPost();
                Session["postStatus"] = "gdgdgdgd";

                if (Session["postStatus"].ToString() != "")
                {
                    //FBpost.Message = Session["postStatus"].ToString();

                    FBpost.Action = new FBAction { Name = "test link", Link = "http://blog.impact-works.com/" };
                    FBpost.Caption = "Test Image Share";
                    FBpost.Description = "Test Image Desc";
                    FBpost.ImageUrl = "http://retailpos.blob.core.windows.net/localitem1/UHSK2KJEKE6VCSP783P59VB6SZ1c822580-d0ff-46fc-af85-681aacef232f.png";
                    FBpost.Message = "Check out test post";
                    FBpost.Name = "Test Post";
                    FBpost.Url = "http://blog.impact-works.com";

                    facebook.PostToWall(currentUser.id.GetValueOrDefault(), FBpost);
                }
            }
            return Content("Posted succeessfully");
        }
```

Comment: Have Facebook approved your use of publish_actions?

Comment: how to get approval for use of publish_actions?

Comment: You submit the permission you need to Facebook

Comment: yes i already submit permission for publish_actios, publish_stream

Comment: how to see that its approved or not?